# Accessing inner folders in Assets folder

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm having the following folders inside my `Assets.xcassets` folder

[screenshot of the error - sorry, i dont have enough rep to show the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kicXn.png)

I'm trying to access the `ca` folder, then `payments` and then the images inside to populate a `UICollectionViewCell`. For the sake of the test, im force unwrapping it (i know its not safe):

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

cell.paymentImageView.image = UIImage(named: "logos/ca/payments/x.png")!
return cell
```

I get a crash and it's says:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

I'm not sure why it's crashing, the files are there. Is it an issue that for every country there are multiple repeated file names in the different folders? Ie xyz.png might be in ca/payments and de/payments as well

Comment: try remove path `logos/ca/payments/` just only put imageName.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This crash because you try force unwrap optional value.

`UIImage(named: "logos/ca/payments/x.png")` is optional value. Incase image doesn't exist in your project, this will be nil.

And we don't require put path when get image, just only image name and extension file like `UIImage(named: "x.png")`

Also `cell.paymentImageView.image` can accept nil image. So this line just only `cell.paymentImageView.image = UIImage(named: "x.png")` will be okey.

Hope this help!

Comment: I got it! Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

A full path is not required for images. Use only the name instead(if you directly added image)

```
cell.paymentImageView.image = UIImage(named: "x.png")!
```

if you are using .xcassets. use name of the image-set instead of individual image

```
cell.paymentImageView.image = UIImage(named: "<IMAGE_SET_NAME>")!
```

Comment: full path is sometimes required by the developer in case he want the same files names under different folder names